# Extract the number of daily users from table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given a start date and end date for every user I would like to count the daily number of users on the platform:

| ID | START | END |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-12-01 | 2022-12-03 |
| 2 | 2022-12-01 | 2022-12-01 |

I want to get an output like this:

| DATE | NUMBER |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-12-01 | 2 |
| 2022-12-02 | 1 |
| 2022-12-03 | 1 |

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: I am stumped on this now my best attempt is a self join but I have no idea on best join conditions

Answer (score 4):

Make a list of all the dates (`generate_series`) and count for each of them.

```sql
with the_table(id, dstart, dend) as 
(
 values
  (1, '2022-12-01'::date, '2022-12-03'::date),
  (2, '2022-12-01', '2022-12-01')
)
select d::date as "DATE", 
      (select count(*) from the_table where d between dstart and dend) as "NUMBER"
from generate_series('2022-12-01'::date,'2022-12-03'::date,interval '1 day') as d;
```

Alternative

```sql
with the_table(id,dstart,dend) as 
(
 values
  (1, '2022-12-01'::date, '2022-12-03'::date),
  (2, '2022-12-01', '2022-12-01')
),
d (id, dlogged) as 
(
 select id, generate_series(dstart,dend,interval '1 day')::date 
 from the_table
) 
select dlogged as "DATE", count(*) as "NUMBER" 
from d group by dlogged;
```